# The row doesn't fade away in UITableView when deleting

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am populating my iOS table view with the names of files inside my database. Everything is displayed in the tableView as expected. The problem comes when i delete it, it deleted the entries in the database but the entry doesn't fade away in the `UITableView`. Here is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle: (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {

        DBHandler *handler;
        [handler ResumeID:[mydataList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; //mydataList contains the array that contains name of all the entries in the DB and is displaying them on the tableview.
        [mydataList removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         NSLog(@"%ld",indexPath.row);



        // Animate the deletion from the table.
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the table do? Anything? Have you debugged the code? Is the `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:` called?

Comment: Yup, I have done the debugging and deleteRowsAtIndexPaths gets the call. But afterwards the exception comes.

Comment: What exception? You never mentioned an exception. My guess is that your data source isn't properly updated before deleting the row from the table view. And you need to call `handler ResumeID...` before removing the object from the array.

Comment: Wait let me perform the debugging this way and will let you know what happens. Good guess!!

Comment: BTW - `handler` is `nil` so calling `ResumeID` does nothing.

Comment: @rmaddy, No the handler is working perfectly and same goes with the database updating.

Comment: Then the code you posted isn't real code. Post real code. In the code you posted you never initialize the `handler` variable.

Comment: Could you please let me know how did you initialised `handler` variable?

Comment: @rmaddy, your comments have been helping. I am performing the debugging according to them

Comment: @ShivaKumarGanthi, you  are right the handler is the actual problem. I am dealing with it. Thanks for your help mate. I will let you know if any problem will come.

Comment: @rmaddy,you are right the handler is the actual problem. I am dealing with it. Thanks for you help mates. I will let you know if any problem will come.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually passing the value which is deleted before, to the `DBHandler`. Check the code,

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
{
    DBHandler *handler ;
    [handler ResumeID:[mydataList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; // Pass the object from the dataSource before deleting the object from the dataSource.

     [mydataList removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // Remove object after passing it to the DBHandler
    NSLog(@"%ld",indexPath.row);
    // Animate the deletion from the table.
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Try this.

Comment: No, the OP's code is correct. You must delete the data before updating the table view.

Comment: @rmaddy, He is actually removing the `[mydataList removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` object from array and then giving the same object handle to the `DBHandler`, `[handler ResumeID:[mydataList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];` 
See this.

Comment: That does appear to be a problem but it doesn't change the fact that you must delete the row in the table view *after* updating the data source, not before.

Comment: Yeah, true! It was my mistake. Anyways thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Update your answer as needed. Point out the issue with needing to update `handler` before deleting the object from the array.

Comment: @ShivaKumarGanthi, I have been trying this way back but it doesn't help and it just not the right way to do it we must delete the data from the database before updating the table view.

Comment: @ejazdogar, Yes that's correct. But, My Point is you are passing the deleted object to the `DBHandler` which actually sends `nil`. How can it delete the exact record when you are sending `nil` as the ID to `DB`!

Comment: I have changed the arrangement your way but the thing is in both cases the ID passed remains the same as its coming from the indexPath.row. The rows are getting deleted from the database perfectly and on the right time but exception comes when it moves to fading.

Comment: Ok! May I know the exception details?

Answer (score 0):

Its a bug of ios7.. the tablerow animations are broken! My fix was to fadeOut the cell right before the tableViewRowAnimation..

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // hide cell, because animations are broken on ios7
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) {
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].alpha = 0.0;
    }

    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
}
```

Comment: I don't have any issues deleting rows under iOS 7. I don't need any tricks to make it work.

Answer (score -1):

after deleting refresh the view 
[tableView reloadData];

Comment: This is overkill. You only need to delete the one row.

Comment: after deleting one row reload the view. how is it overkilling ?

Comment: The OP's code is correct. Just call `deleteRowsAtIndexPath` instead of reloading the entire table.

Comment: @LightYagami, its a good alternate way even though I have been doing this but it won't help.

Comment: thanks for the advice will keep in mind next time i code anywhere near tableview , cheers